# Proceeding to next pages, using URL class

Tags: java

Not long time ago I asked some question that helped me progress with my project.
Lately, I ran into a new problem. 
I am using information from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/.
I run a search, parse the source code to get the information I need from the table and use it.

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(Vars.searchLink + Vars.searchWord);
        conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
            if(inputLine.contains("gene-id"))
                break;
```

After running this, inputLine will contain the line that contains the information I need.

The problem is that I cannot proceed past the first page because the rest of the pages have an identical URL.
No page indication in the url, so I am stuck with that.

I need to either find a solution and get next pages or use another trick to get the information.(I tried to compare page1 and page2's source codes, but both contain a certain hexadecimal code, which cannot be guessed)

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Hi Orel, If your website functionality running smothly, you can free to use Jsoup (Best framework to manipulate HTML DOM elements using Java)

Comment: check out this: [MultiPageLink](https://github.com/srijiths/Web-Pagination-Finder/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sree/textbytes/nextpage/MultiPageLink.java)

Comment: I would suggest, record script in JMeter, you will come to know all the HTTP requests that are getting executed when you navigate to page 2 or any other page.